# How to specify nested random effects in a model with nested fixed effects

Tags: mixed-model, nested-data

I have an experiment predicting $y$ from the interaction of two two-level categorical independent variables, $x$ and $z$. (My actual design is more complicated, but I'm simplifying here to get at the root of my question.) These data are from a psychology experiment where multiple subjects respond to multiple items, so I have two sources of random effects: subject and item.

I've coded the variables using deviation coding, so that level 1 of $x$ is $-0.5$ and level 2 is $0.5$. Likewise for $z$. Call these codings $x_n$ and $z_n$.

$x$ is a between-subjects but within-items variable (e.g., whether the subject wears glasses or not). In contrast, $z$ is between-items but within-subjects (e.g., whether a picture is of an indoor or an outdoor setting). (These aren't my actual predictors, but they give an idea of the kinds of predictors that are necessarily between-subjects or between-items like the ones I'm actually using.)

In other words, subjects are nested within levels of $x$ but not $z$ (a subject either wears glasses or doesn't, but sees both indoor and outdoor pictures). Contrariwise, items are nested within levels of $z$ but not $x$ (each picture is of either an indoor or an outdoor setting, but all pictures are seen both by subjects who wear glasses and by subjects who don't). My research question concerns the effects of $x$, $z$, and their interaction on $y$ (say, ratings of how happy the picture makes them feel or whatever).

I'm following the advice in [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3881361/) and using the maximal random effects structure justified by the model design (I'm using `brms`, so I'm not worried about convergence as such). I've run the following model, and found evidence for the interaction of $x_n$ and $z_n$:

```
y ~ x.n * z.n + 
    (1 + z.n | x.n:subject) + 
    (1 + x.n | z.n:item)
```

In order to explore the source of this interaction, I want to run a model that nests $x$ within each value of $z$. (To address the question of, e.g., is there an effect of wearing glasses for both indoor and outdoor pictures?) To do this, I create two new predictor variables as follows:

```
data$x.in.z1.n <- ifelse(data$z == 'z1', x.n, 0)
data$x.in.z2.n <- ifelse(data$z == 'z2', x.n, 0)
```

Now, the fixed effects of the nested model should be the following, I think:

```
y ~ x.in.z1.n + x.in.z2.n + z.n
```

The results of this model will address the question of what effect $x$ has within each level of $z$ (while also including room for a main effect of $z_n$, which should be identical to its effect in the crossed model). For instance, an effect of `x.in.z1.n` could tell us that there is evidence that $x$ has a reliable effect on $y$ in condition $z_1$.

What I'm unsure about is exactly what the random effects structure should look like for this model, given that levels of $x$ are nested within subjects, and levels of $z$ are nested within items. My question is both about the actual model structure, as well as how it should be specified in R (for `brms`'s `brm`, if it makes any difference). Here's a guess:

```
y ~ x.in.z1.n + x.in.z2.n + z.n +
    (1 | (x.in.z1.n + x.in.z2.n):subject) +
    (1 + (x.in.z1.n + x.in.z2.n) | z.n:item)
```

My thought here is that you can get back to $x_n$ by adding the vectors `x.in.z1.n` and `x.in.z2.n`, so wherever $x_n$ went before, I can substitute the sum of those two to get the proper nesting structure for the random effects.* Am I thinking about this right?

---

* Also, if that's right, would this be equivalent? Just curious.

```
y ~ x.in.z1.n + x.in.z2.n + z.n +
    (1 | x.in.z1.n:subject + x.in.z2.n:subject) +
    (1 + x.in.z1.n + x.in.z2.n | z.n:item)
```